# Effect of extern(C) for function type in Dlang

Tags: function, d

If a function type alias is defined inside `extern(C)` as in the following example:

```
extern(C) {
  alias F = void function(int x);
}
```

will this warrant that the aliased type is `extern(C)`?

Or do I need to write

```
extern(C) {
  alias F = extern(C) void function(int x);
}
```

or just

```
alias F = extern(C) void function(int x);
```

for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a scoped attribute or declaration applies to all symbols inside its scope (except they explicitly overwrite it or a nested scope overwrites it).
Proof:

```
extern(C) {
  alias F = void function(int x);
}
alias G = void function(int x);
alias H = extern(C) void function(int x);

pragma(msg, F.mangleof); // PUiZv
pragma(msg, G.mangleof); // PFiZv
pragma(msg, H.mangleof); // PUiZv
```

Check [it out for yourself on run.dlang.io](https://run.dlang.io/is/FiGoaE).